# How can I use unicode characters in an encrypted maxscript

Tags: maxscript

I have a `.ms` file type with the symbols ✖ and ✔ that I want to use.

Once I evaluate this file those characters appear correctly like so:

[image]

but not after encrypting the file to `.mse`, they then appear as a question marks like so:

[image]

---

Here's a snippet of code in it's raw `.ms` form. You will need to run this following piece of code to encrypt it. `encryptScript @"path\to\file.ms" version:1`

```
/* This file is saved with encoding UTF-8
and the 2 special characters show fine.

But when I 'encryptScript @"path\to\file.ms" version:1' they don't display correctly. */

rollout testRol "Test"
(
  button ui_btn_test "✔"
  label  ui_lbl_test "✖"
  )
createDialog testRol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape them like this:

```
button ui_btn_test "\x2714"
label  ui_lbl_test "\x2716"
```

Comment: Cheers. Ah, so it's the hexadecimal value [graphemica.com](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%94)